# Getting text to speech activity to work at the same time as an onclick go to a new xml

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working on an app and I want the app to use text to speech to tell the user what button they have just pressed. I am having problems getting my button to work properly with the two conflicting activities. I am able to make it work either doing only text to speech or only when pressing it goes to a different page, but I can't get it to do both at the same time. Currently it sends the user to the new menu without playing the text to speech but I am finally getting an error from my LogCat so I figured it is fixable. I have included my LogCat and the java. I have commented above and below where the problem code is.

```
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328): Activity com.example.com.proto1.menu has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1@4051eb10 that was originally bound here
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.com.proto1.menu has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1@4051eb10 that was originally bound here
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:938)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:833)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:867)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:467)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:433)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at com.example.com.proto1.menu.onActivityResult(menu.java:122)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-25 12:52:35.031: E/ActivityThread(328):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**menu.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class menu extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener,
        OnClickListener {

    TextToSpeech mTts;
    Button speakButton;

    // TTS object
    public TextToSpeech myTTS;
    // status check code
    public int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle aboutmenu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(aboutmenu);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainx);

        SpeakingAndroid speak = new SpeakingAndroid();

        // get a reference to the button element listed in the XML layout
        speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
        // listen for clicks
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // check for TTS data
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

        // Setting up the button references
        Button info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutbutton);
        Button voice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voicebutton);

        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.INFOSCREEN"));

            }
        });

        voice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });
// This is the start of the problem area
        starteyephone();
        {
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent voiceIntent = new Intent(
                            "android.intent.action.RECOGNITIONMENU");
                    startActivity(voiceIntent);

                }
            });
        }

    }


    private void starteyephone() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    // respond to button clicks
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // get the text entered
        speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
        String words = speakButton.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words);
    }

    //this is the end of the problem area


    // speak the user text
    public void speakWords(String speech) {

        // speak straight away
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    // act on result of TTS data check
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            } else {
                // no data - install it now
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    // setup TTS
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        // check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of problems here:

1. You initialize the `TextToSpeech` using the Context of the menu activity. That means that when the menu activity is destroyed, the `TextToSpeech` instance will be leaked because it is never properly shutdown (this is probably why you see that error in your logcat). You need to either call `myTTS.shutdown()` in `menu.onDestroy()` or you need to pass `getApplicationContext()` as the context parameter when initializing `TextToSpeech` here:

   myTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);

   Note: If you use the application context, then you need to determine when you don't need the TTS anymore and call `shutdown()` on it at that time.
2. You are using `android.intent.action.RECOGNITIONMENU` but this Intent is used for speech recognition (ie: Speech to text), not Text to Speech. I don't understand what you are trying to do here.
3. I still don't understand your exact problem. It seems to me that the code you have posted should speak the text of the button. What else do you expect to happen here?

**EDIT: Add observation**

I see now that you are calling `setOnClickListener()` on the `speakButton` twice. Once at the beginning of `onCreate()` and then again in your "problem section". You can't set more than one onClickListener, so the first one is overwritten. You should just move this code:

```
Intent voiceIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.RECOGNITIONMENU");
startActivity(voiceIntent);
```

into your existing `onClick()` method.

Comment: To address your question in the 3rd and second question. When I press the button I don't want it to only speak the text on the button but send the user to a new menu. The new menu has a speech recognition activity and that is why the intent has that name.  Now my question is where exactly in my code do I put the code you listed in part 1?

Comment: Ok. You should be able to speak the text and also start a new intent to send the user to another activity. Exactly what are you seeing when that happens? In the logcat you can see which intents are sent and which activities are started. Or you can add some debug logging to track what is going on.

Comment: I added another observation to my answer. Have a look.

Comment: I still don't know where to put the getapplicationcontext and shutdown into my code. Right now the app starts the intent that sends me to a new activity but doesn't play the text to speech.